# How to use CTE to get a query repeated for multiple inputs?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT **top 1** account, date, result
FROM table_1 as t1
JOIN table_2 at t2 ON t1.accountId = t2.frn_accountId
WHERE accountID = 1
ORDER BY date
```

This query returns the result that I want however I want that result for multiple accountID. They query should return the top 1 value for each accountID.

The query that produce the list of the accountID-s is:

```
SELECT accountID from lskin WHERE refname LIKE '%BHA%' and isactive = 1
```

How can I write this query so it can produce the desired result? I have been playing around with CTE but haven't been able to make it correct. It doesn't have to be with CTE, I just thought it can be easier using CTE...

Comment: @scsimon. I can not group by account because the "result" column doesn't allow me to do so. That column is not same for all the rows and I only want to get the result for the latest row. (yes you are right, I have to put a DESC on my order by clause)

Comment: that's fine... there's an inner join query that works for you in my answer

Comment: put the definition of the table in the question, in which table are the date and result column? What does it mean the result column is not the same for all the rows? You need to retrieve different columns based on some criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is CTE solution.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT account
        , date
        , result
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.accountId ORDER BY date DESC) AS Rownum
    FROM table_1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2 
        ON t1.accountId = t2.frn_accountId
    INNER JOIN lskin AS l 
        ON l.accountID = t1.accountID 
    WHERE l.refname LIKE '%BHA%'
) a
WHERE a.Rownum = 1;
```

Comment: There isn't a CTE there. Just a very handy window function (OVER).

Comment: +1 for using OVER(). :-)  Looking back at this answer, it actually brings up another important question about the data structure. This answer will filter for lskin.refname before it calculates the ROW_NUMBER(), so there may be other orders if an accountID can have multiple refnames in lskin. Regardless, this goes all the way back to a need for some data definition and examples of what you have and what you expect. @DoArNa

Answer (score 0):

Use max on your date and group by the account, or what ever columns are appropriate.

```
SELECT 
    account, 
    DT = max(date), 
    result
FROM table_1 as t1
JOIN table_2 as t2 ON t1.accountId = t2.frn_accountId
JOIN lskin as l on l.accountID = t1.accountID 
WHERE l.refname like '%BHA%'
GROUP BY
    account
    ,result
```

If the grouping isn't correct, just join to a sub-query to limit it with max date. Just change the table names as necessary.

```
SELECT 
    account, 
    date, 
    result
FROM table_1 as t1
JOIN table_2 as t2 ON t1.accountId = t2.frn_accountId
JOIN lskin as l on l.accountID = t1.accountID 
INNER JOIN (select max(date) dt, accountID from table_1 group by accountID) tt on tt.dt = t1.accountId and tt.accountId = t1.accountId
WHERE l.refname like '%BHA%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the CTE at the top. That's just test data.

```
/* CTE Test Data */
; WITH table_1 AS ( 
    SELECT 1 AS accountID, 'acc1' AS account UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS accountID, 'acc2' AS account UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS accountID, 'acc3' AS account
)
, table_2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS frn_accountID, 'new1' AS result, GETDATE() AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS frn_accountID, 'mid1' AS result, GETDATE()-1 AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS frn_accountID, 'old1' AS result, GETDATE()-2 AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS frn_accountID, 'new2' AS result, GETDATE() AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS frn_accountID, 'mid2' AS result, GETDATE()-1 AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS frn_accountID, 'old2' AS result, GETDATE()-2 AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS frn_accountID, 'new3' AS result, GETDATE() AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS frn_accountID, 'mid3' AS result, GETDATE()-1 AS [date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS frn_accountID, 'old3' AS result, GETDATE()-2 AS [date]

)
, lskin AS ( 
    SELECT 1 AS accountID, 'purple' AS refName, 1 AS isActive UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS accountID, 'blue' AS refName, 1 AS isActive UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS accountID, 'orange' AS refName, 0 AS isActive UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS accountID, 'blue' AS refName, 1 AS isActive
)
, 
/* Just use the below and remove comment markers around WITH to build Orders CTE. */
/* ; WITH */ 
theCTE AS (   
SELECT s1.accountID, s1.account, s1.result, s1.[date]
FROM (
    SELECT t1.accountid, t1.account, t2.result, t2.[date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.account ORDER BY t2.[date]) AS rn
    FROM table_1 t1
    INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.accountID = t2.frn_accountID
) s1
WHERE s1.rn = 1  
)
SELECT lskin.accountID 
FROM lskin
INNER JOIN theCTE ON theCTE.accountid = lskin.accountID
WHERE lskin.refName LIKE '%blue%'
    AND lskin.isActive = 1
;
```

EDITED:
I'm still making a lot of assumptions about your data structure. And again, make sure you're querying what you need. CTEs are awesome, but you don't want to accidentally filter out expected results.

Comment: Also note that your current rn filter is pulling the oldest order. Change that to ORDER BY [date] DESC to get the newest order in each group.

Comment: Without knowing your data structure, it's hard to give you what you're looking for. Are you able to provide an example or a fiddle?

Comment: dbFiddle makes it a little clearer.  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=60ef489a4c6b1215e7a147df1d825a6c